# Why is this cast redundant?

Tags: c#, casting, overloading

I have a method with the following overloads:

```
string Call(string function, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, object body)
string Call(string function, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, JObject body)
```

Now I added another overload:

```
string Call(string function)
{
    return Call(function, null, (JObject) null);
}
```

I added a cast to `JObject` so the compiler knows which overload it should use. But Visual Studio tells me that the cast is redundant. But why isn't my call ambiguous without the cast?

Comment: Even if it isn't ambiguous to the compiler i would keep the cast there as it could be ambiguous to the person reading the code

Comment: @jean No, that's not the reason. I'm telling the compiler which overload to use. And it _does_ matter which method overload is being used since they could have completely different implementations. `null` is `null`, but the cast here is a hint which overload should be used.

Comment: @jean I'm afraid this is wrong again. The cast is only redundant because the compiler will _still_ use the `JObject` overload even if I don't cast to `JObject` because it uses the most specific overload that matches the parameters, and `null` can match anything and `JObject` _is_ more specific than `object`. See Jon Skeet's answer for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

> But why isn't my call ambiguous without the cast?

Because the overload with the `JObject` parameter is "better" than the overload with the `object` parameter... because the conversion from `null` to `JObject` is "better" than the conversion from `null` to `object`.

`JObject` is more specific than `object`, because there's an implicit conversion from `JObject` to `object`, but not vice versa.

If the final parameter for the first method were `string` instead (for example) then neither overload would be better than the other, and the call *would* be ambiguous without the cast.

See section 7.5.3 of the C# 5 specification for all the intricate details. In particular, section 7.5.3.5 ("better conversion target") is relevant here.

Comment: Even if a cast isn't necessary with the class as it exists today, failure to cast the `null` will make the calling code very brittle, since the addition of *almost any* additional reference-type overload would break calling code which doesn't cast.  I would not consider any cast of a null reference to be "redundant" in cases where there's any realistic possibility of additional reference-type overloads that might become ambiguous, or even for that matter in cases where a particular overload is deemed "better" by the rules but it's far from obvious that it's better in any practical sense.

Comment: BTW, I've long thought that languages with overloading would benefit greatly from a means of using attributes or some other means to specify certain overloads should be considered "preferred" if they're usable, while others should be considered only as "fallbacks"; I've also thought it would be helpful if an overload could specify a parameter type of `null`.  Do you know of any languages that do such things?

Comment: @supercat: Nope, I'm afraid not.

Comment: @supercat: C++11 and later introduce `nullptr_t`, which can be used as a parameter type.  But null pointer literals are still implicitly convertible to `int` and object pointer types, so that doesn't help much with overload resolution.  A trailing variadic parameter list (`...`) in C++ (all versions) is pretty good at making a particular overload less preferred.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I wonder why languages don't generally allow a prioritizing mechanism?  I would think that allowing programmers to prioritize overloads (and requiring prioritization in ambiguous cases) would be easier than trying to formulate and implement rules that will generally pick the most useful overload in cases where several could work, and would also ease the "brittle base class" problem.

Comment: @supercat: Hmm... I guess it makes the language more complicated, in that you'd presumably still want to support overloading *without* the explicit prioritization...

Comment: @JonSkeet: One would want to allow overloading without explicit prioritization, but perhaps not handle all the cases.  As it is, I have a suspicion that some of the motivation for Java's making `float` implicitly convert to `double` but not vice versa (behavior borrowed in .NET) was to ensure that a function with `(float,float)` and `(double,double)` overloads would prefer the latter when invoked with a `float` and a `double`; unfortunately, such behavior means that the `(float,float)` overload will be preferred when passing a `float` and a `long`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: If instead of jinxing the implicit conversion rules to ensure that mixed float-double operations would use double-double overloads, the languages simply allowed a programmer to say the double-double overloads were preferred (even if bidirectional float/double implicit conversions existed), that would have yielded correct behavior when passing (float,double), (float,long), or any other operand combination.

Comment: @supercat If you really want to specify the overload manually, why not just have a new uniquely named function?

Comment: @Superbest: Because in many cases the person writing the method group will know more about which overloads are apt to be better than would the author of client code or the language designer.